# Replace YouTube watch <a> with <iframe> embeding the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Today is my first day with JavaScript and jQuery.

I have experience with HTML, PHP, Python, CSS.

In my experience, I found the best way to learn was to just do it, learning along the way.

I had an idea for a Chrome extension (no clue if it is original, I just wanted to learn), where on YouTube, you hover over a link to a video and it loads the video in an iframe. Getting it on click is not what I am doing. At the moment I am just using hover. But, I have no idea how to make it an iframe.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "HoverTube",
  "description": "Hover over any video on YouTube and it will begin to play without even having to click it. Perfect for those who are tight on resources, and don't want to load a whole new page for just 1 video.",
  "version": "0.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.youtube.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "hover.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**hover.js**

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){
    if (this.href.includes("watch")){
            //Take this.href and convert it to <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/linkfromthehref" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method to just replace the `<a>` with the iframe as HTML text with the URL modified using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
$('body').on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){
    if (this.href.includes("watch")){
        $(this).replaceWith('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' +this.href.replace(/[^=]*=/,'')+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    }
})
```

In addition to just inserting it, you should give it an ID. It would probably be better from a UI point of view to pick one place on the page to display the iframe and reuse that location. Potentially even better, would be to have a fly-out/popup that only displays the iframe while the link is hovered and then destroys it when the link is no longer hovered.

Comment: @Will I re-read your question and updated the answer to actually reflect what you requested (i.e. replace, not add, the `<iframe>`)